# Is there a better approach to count sportsmens rating?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a code that count sportsmens rating  , for example if you have same rating as person before  you will have same score number :

```
    import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ratingScore = [100, 90, 90, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40];

  const getRatingNum = (rating) => {
    const ratingScore = [];
    rating.forEach((el, i, arr) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        ratingScore.push(1);
        return;
      }

      if (arr[i - 1] > el) {
        const newScore = ratingScore.at(-1) + 1;
        ratingScore.push(newScore);
        return;
      }

      if (arr[i - 1] === el) {
        const newScore = ratingScore.at(-1);
        ratingScore.push(newScore);
        return;
      }
    });

    return ratingScore;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ratingScore.map((el, i) => {
        return (
          <p key={Math.random() * 10}>
            {getRatingNum(ratingScore)[i]}. {el}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

link to live example - https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-williams-2s5dz?file=/src/App.js

Is there a better approach to count sportsmens rating?

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say *f you have same rating as person before you will have same rating number*? Please be clear...

Comment: If the sportsmans have same score , for example 90 , they will have same position in rating

Comment: what should be your expected result?

Comment: For example we Mark with score 100 , he will have  number 1  , then we have Mike and Tom with score 90 , they will have number two and so on

Comment: I want to know , is there better way to count rating

Comment: Yes there might be but what should be your expected result. Would you mind If you could add in your code?

Comment: My code is in question and there is a link with live example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238162/discussion-between-quintis-and-decpk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about such simple approach (pseudocode):

```
 let ratings = [1], curr_rating = 1

 for (let i = 1; i < ratingScore.length; i++) {
    if ratingScore[i] < ratingScore[i - 1] {
          curr_rating++
       }
    ratings.push(curr_rating)
 }
```

Comment: Looks better that my approach , and possible reduce array method will be  better ?

Comment: Perhaps yes, but I am not familiar with JS.

Comment: Or with `map`: `const ratings = ratingScore .map (((n = 1) => (r, i, a) => i > 0 && r < a [i - 1] ? ++n : n)())`.  this only works if the inputs will always be in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do as:

```
const getRatingNum = ( rating ) => {
        let result = [], count = 0;
        ratingScore.forEach( ( n ) => {
            if (!result.length || result[result.length - 1].key !== n) result.push( { key: n, count: ++count } );
            else result.push( { key: n, count: result[result.length - 1].count } );
        } );

        return result;
    };
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const ratingScore = [100, 90, 90, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40];

    const getRatingNum = ( rating ) => {
        let result = [], count = 0;
        ratingScore.forEach( ( n ) => {
            if (!result.length || result[result.length - 1].key !== n) result.push( { key: n, count: ++count } );
            else result.push( { key: n, count: result[result.length - 1].count } );
        } );

        return result;
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
        {
            getRatingNum(ratingScore).map((o, i) => {
                return (
                    <p key={i}>{o.count}. {o.key}</p>
                )
            })
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```